# MVC Web API/Rest: Requests by related object

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I got two controllers; ProjectController and DocumentController. One project can have several documents.

If I want to get documents by projectid, how and where should that be done using REST? (In general I havent got how REST deals with related data)

**Edit:** Found [MVC Web API, get sub items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10555323/mvc-web-api-get-sub-items) that might be what I'm looking for.

Ivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should be done in the DocumentController. Below is an example

```
public class DocumentController : ApiController {

    public IQueryable<Document> GetDocs() 
    {

        //get db context 

            return db.documents;

    }

    public ICollection<Document> Get(int id)
    {
        return db.documents.where(d = d.ProjectId == id);

    }

}
```

The IQuerable version can be queried using odata filter query. like below:

```
http://server:port/api/Document/getdocs?$filter=ProjectId eq ‘1'
http://server:port/api/Document/getdocs?$filter=DocumentId eq ‘1001'
```

(you will have to modify the MapHttpRoute to register this route)

The get version (second function) will simply return collection based on the project id.